# GIT Setup and access via IIS on remote server on local network

Tags: git, iis, ssh, installation

thank you for reading the question.

### Case:

development machine *Win7* / Server *win2012* - BOTH on the same network and same login and credentials (have admin access to the server)
Installed **GIT** & **GITHUB** on the server and created *bare* directory in a shared directory and gave ALL Permissions to all required parties including myself
Installed GIT on local machine as well.
On the server pointed IIS to shared directory AS a virtual directory
Locally, on both machines there are no issues and I can configure locally.
I have a source code that I need to push to the NEW GIT setup to examine if it will work for everybody in the team.

### Problem:

Can not connect from local machine to `remote GIT` Server.

### Comments and process so far:

All examples happily cover UNIX environments and URL samples across the net all refer to `UNIX path` structure. I need help on how to share PROPERLY (direct examples / commands) GIT via IIS on Win2012 Server and how to add `remote` IIS shared repository to local machine.
Can access the server via https in the browser.

**HELP!!! :-D**

Answer (score 0):

everybody.
After spending more days to work out the basic solution, I came to the point where We have chosen the basic industry tools that after spending more time again, we managed to get to work.

So, **THIS is NOT a direct Answer, but rather than SOLUTION.**

End result:

1. Install on Win2012 Server, the Bonobo GIT Server (http://bonobogitserver.com/) using default instructions.
2. Install "GIT for Windows" and few other optional Clients being available "GIT GUI" and "TortoiseGit". I like Tortoise tools, so it did work for me again.
3. To get it working on internal secure (important note) office network, I disabled all security on both sides and allowed "Allow push for anonymous repositories" to get to talk to each other and not to waste any more time.

so far, it works.

PS: Happy to hear other answers and options to get it to work directly via IIS without additional app in the middle.